# When does the system of equations have initly solution, no solutions, and only one solution

Tags: matrices

I am trying to solve this math problem. So far I am bad at it. I nedd to determine for what given x does the system of linear equations has no solutions, has one solution, or infinetly many solutions.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      2&1&1&0\\
      -2k&k&9&6\\
      2&2&k&1      
    \end{array}
\right] $$

I would appreciate if somebody would write step by step solution for this or similar problem, because I want to understand how it is done, because I have no idea how to solve this and I want to understand it.

Thanks!!!

EDIT: I got using Cramer system 3 and -3/2 for k. I have no idea is this correct or not, so how can I check it?

Comment: You can use Cramer's rule to find the conditions on $k$ which produce each case.

Comment: I know but I have no expirience with that and finding information about solving that type of problem is very hard to find.

Comment: Instead of expecting someone will solve this problem for you and write it down step by step, try to do some work of your own and only discuss the steps where you are stuck. For example, have you tried to perform elimination on your matrix?

Comment: I dont expect that anybody solve this problem for me, as I have wrote, I want to understand how to solve it, but I have no idea how to start or how to end. I learn best when I see some example, and example of this type are very hard to find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the two values for $k$, in the following sense.

If you row reduce your matrix, you should obtain (barring mistakes) a matrix in the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 1 & | & 0\\
0 & 1 & k-1 & | & 6\\
0 & 0 & -2 k^{2} + 3 k + 9 & | & 6 - 2 k
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now the roots of $-2 k^{2} + 3 k + 9 = 0$ are indeed $k = 3$ and $k = - 3/2$. But the solutions behave differently for the two values of $k$. You have

- If $k \notin \{ 3, -3/2 \}$, then there's a unique solution.
- If $k = -3/2$, then there is no solution, as the last equation in the row reduced system is $0 = 9$.
- If $k = 3$, the last equation vanishes, and you have one free variable, and thus, infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

you need to row reduce the matrix, this will involve multiplying the rows by k sometimes. Linear equation would mean you have 3 leading ones( no free variables), infinite solutions would mean your have 2 leading ones( 1 free variable), and no solution would be where you have a row of 0s but the last number is not zero. You accomplish this by finding which value of k satisfies these conditions after getting to row echelon form